# Callback url appends # tag before access_token parameter

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is callback that I am getting from faceboook:

http://puneet.com/fb/response.php#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&expires_in=6428&state=c7c8de9ea7e6acd251cb5b1cb901c7ce

I am not able to parse the access_token. It says:

```
Undefined index: access_token.
```

I have tried all `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_SERVER`.. what is the problem?

This is my login url parameters array:

```
array(
    'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://puneet.com/fb/response.php',
    'response_type' => 'token',
    'display' => 'popup'    
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: Can you post the code which produces this error message.

Comment: You're using the wrong flow. The response_type you request should be an authorization code. You then exchange that on the PHP side for an access token. What you're doing right now is intended for javascript-only clients without a server counterpart.

Comment: Read this page for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko facebook is returning me the callback with access token. i cannot print error message if facebook is not returning an exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see the problem: in the URL you should use the `?` instead of `#`:

```
http://puneet.com/fb/response.php?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&expires_in=6428&state=c7c8de9ea7e6acd251cb5b1cb901c7ce
```

Comment: He's not creating the URL. Facebook is. This is because he's sending the wrong information to FB. (`response_type` should not be `token`)

Comment: @PuneetSethi Yes, and the link I posted in a comment on your question has information on exchanging that for an `access_token`

Comment: @PuneetSethi Please read the link I sent you. You're not likely to get other answers to this question. You _can not_ request an access token the way that you are doing it now, and use it in PHP. You MUST use the server-based OAuth flow by requesting an authorization code and then exchanging it for a token.